# Submit Decimal/Float in URL Request with Swift

Tags: swift, url, post, floating-point, decimal

How can a value such as "1.5" be passed in a a URL POST request using swift?

For example:

```
let number = "1.5"
let numberValue = number.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let server:String = "www.someserver.com"
let phpFile:String = "/php/SomePHPScript.php"
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://\(server)\(phpFile)")           
let url = NSURL(string: "?value=\(numberValue)", relativeToURL: baseURL) 
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var dataString = ""
let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData
// etc...
```

This compiles fine but crashes on execution. It seems converting this to JSON would fix it, but is there cleaner way?

**EDIT**

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) returns` optional. It needed to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` returns optional. It needed to be unwrapped.